# Cartoon where kids play a game with runes that give them powers

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a show where kids play a game with runes. They play in a competition-like sport. I believe there were 4 or 5 kids. The runes allowed them to have certain powers. One in particular could Naruto-run and a barrier appeared behind her like in *Tron*.

I think they went up a mountain and used a platform to teleport to another place where they would train and play this sport. The more I think about it, it could have been a bracelet instead of a rune.

It was an English story and I watched it about 8 years ago. I cannot remember the channel. It was basically a competition if I remember correctly. Another power I do now remember was an alien using the bracelet-thing that was on their arm to freeze the other players. The game was basically like basketball where they had to throw a ball through a hole. I hope this helps the search a little bit better.

Another thing I remember was that it was on the same channel as the show where kids had to time travel to save the world and the show *Rescue Heroes* about fire fighters and other people like police men that saved the world.

Comment: Can you remember any of the other powers the kids got? How many were there? Why were they playing this, a game, sport, competition? Was it a bracelet or rune? How did they work? Can you remember any plot elements to this? When did you watch this? Was it in English? What channel? If you can remember anything else can you [edit] that detail into your question?

Comment: [This meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) is a good place to start for eliciting further details.

Comment: Runes makes me think of [Di-Gata Defenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di-Gata_Defenders), but that's not really about a sport.

Comment: @Jerixport It seems you've created two accounts, you might want to follow the instructions on [how to merge them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way you can take ownership of your question again and edit directly without review.

Comment: And maybe *Histeria* for the time travel, which suggests Kids WB around 2000-2002.

Comment: Hmm... nothing at https://www.imdb.com/list/ls049976097/ is looking right to me.