# Cartoon Network cartoon about power stones with Greek lettering

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm searching for the name of a cartoon I watched in my childhood on Cartoon Network. In this cartoon everyone uses a cube shaped stone for power. There was a Greek letter in every single stone. I remember one of the villain using this type of wrist gauntlet for power:

[image: black strapped forearm gauntlet]

I also remember **yin yang** symbol very commonly featured in this cartoon.

[image: black and white yin yang]

Comment: How did they use the stone for power? Was it rolled like a dice?

Comment: As far as I remember, they used to throw the stone or place the stone in the hand to activate it. Not sure which one is correct.

Comment: Similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/235073/23243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Di-Gata Defenders*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di-Gata_Defenders)?

[image: Title image for the show, showing cubes with sigils]

> The series follows the travels and adventures of six teenagers, part of an organization called the Di-Gata Defenders. Their mission as heroes is to defend RaDos against evil factions.

....

> Before the humans arrived in this world, mystical beings called the Primordials roamed the realm. Their bodies used mystical energies as their life force. As they died, their life force leeched into the rocks of Di-Gata Mountains. Humans soon crash landed on the planet, caused by a stowaway creature named the Wrath-norak and a virus from their dying planet. Under Rados' sun, man's skin colour soon changed. Man was then able to mine the enchanted rocks found in the mountains, but were only able to recover energy from eight of the eleven sigils. Many rocks were mined by man, then carved into dice-like Di-Gata stones, and these were then carved with the sigil their power contained. From this point onward, anyone who used these stones were called stone casters or stone-slingers. It was believed that the first people who used these stones of power were called the Chi'Brek Tribe. This tribe was also the first tribe to document the arrival of the human race onto the planet.

Comment: That's absolutely correct! Thank you so much for everyone's effort! Love you all!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :) I've answered this one before, which means your question will be closed as a duplicate, but you will still get any further upvotes made. It just ties things together in the system.